# Finding a specific basis for an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be $\mathbb C$-vector space of dimension $3$. Let $f$ be non zero endomorphism of $E$ such that $f^2=0$. show that there exists a basis $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\} $ of $E$ where the matrix of $f$ is given by :

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

My try : since $f$ is non zero, there exists $x\in E$ such that $f(x)\not =0$. Take $b_1=f(x)$ and $b_2=x$. Now $b_1,b_2$ can easily shown to be linearly independent. By the exchange lemma we can find $b_3$ in another generating system of $E$ to make $b_1,b_2,b_3$ into a basis of $E$. Now clearly $f(b_1)=f^2(x)=0$ and $f(b_2)=f(x)=b_1$. Now how to find  a $b_3$ such that $f(b_3)=0$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ is a basis of $E$? Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** For the linear independence of $b_1,b_2$, if $\alpha x+\beta f(x)=0$ then we apply $f$ to get $\alpha f(x)=0$ and since $f(x)\not =0$ then $\alpha=0$ it remains that $\beta f(x)=0$ and again this gives that $\beta=0$.

Comment: Have you studied (1)eigenvectors and eigenvalues , (2) The Jordan Canonical Form of matrix ? Anyway, you're on the right path: how could try to prove linear independence?

Comment: We don't have the matrix of $f$ to compute its eigenvalues. The only informations we have is that $f^2=0$ and $f\not =0$.

Comment: You don't need a matrix representing $\;f\;$ to know its eigenvalues: $\;f\;$ is *nilpotent* and thus its only  eigenvalue is zero...!

Comment: @DonAntonio I made an edit to show the linear independence.

Comment: well done....... +1

Answer (score 2):

You should know that $\;x^3\;$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\;f\;$ and, by the given info, $\;x^2\;$ is its minimal polynomial, and from here that its Jordan Canonical Form **has to be** exactly what is written in your question...

**Added by the comment below:** An idea:

It can't be $\;\dim\ker f=0\,,\,3\;$ (why?), so suppose $\;\dim\ker f=1\;$ . By the dimension theorem:

$$3=\dim\ker f+\dim\,\text{Im}\,\implies \dim\,\text{Im}\,f=2$$Take now $\;u\notin\ker f\;\implies \ker f=\langle f(u)\rangle\;$ (why?) , but we also trivially have that

$\;f(u)\in\text{Im}\,f\;$, so we can choose $\;f(v)\in\text{Im}\,f\;$ s.t. $\;\{f(u),f(v)\}\;$ basis of $\;\text{Im}\,f\;$ and thus

$\;\{u,f(u),f(v)\}\;$ is a basis of $\;E\;$, and then we have that for all $\;x\in E\;\;\exists\,a,b,c\in\Bbb C\;\;s.t.$

$$x=au+bf(u)+cf(v)\implies f(x)=f(au)+bf^2u+cf^v=f(au)\implies$$

$$x-au\in\ker f=\langle f(u)\rangle\implies x=au+tf(u)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb C$$

and this is a contradiction (to **what** ?).

Thus, it must be that $\;\dim\ker f=2\;$ and rom here you can take two *linearly independent* $\;u,v\in \ker f\implies f(u)=f(v)=0\;$ that'll be part of a basis, as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio . I'm looking for an answer that ovoids characteristic polynomial and determinant. Can we show the existence of $b_3$ with the given properties?

Comment: Actually $\dim \ker f=2$ follows immediately from the fact that $f^2=0$ so $Imf\subset \ker f$ combined with the rank  nullity theorem. Now following your notation, $b_1=u$ and $b_3=v$ it remains to find $b_2$ such that $f(b_2)=u$ which amounts to show that $u\in Imf$ where $\dim Imf=1$ so a basis for $Imf=\{w\}$ so it amount to show that there exists some non zero scalar $\alpha$ such that $u=\alpha w$, can you tell me please how to find this $\alpha$? Thank you for your help!!